# how do i make my death menu wait 3 seconds to set active after the player died?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile

hi everyone and thank you for your help, so i made this game where i have 2 players i can switch by touching the right half of the screen. Today i wanted to add an explosion when my player dies, but my death menu spawn as soon as the player dies so the particles are hidden by it. i tried using Waitforseconds but it doesnt work (also can you explain me why? im a rookie). Here is the code's parts i think you need to see:

this is in my OnTriggerCollision

```
  if(collision.gameObject.tag == "spikes")
        {
            Break();
            theGameManager.RestartGame();
            moveSpeed = moveSpeedStore;
            speedMilestoneCount = speedMilestoneCountStore;
            speedIncreaseMilestone = speedIncreaseMilestoneStore;
        }
    }

    private void Break()
    {
        if(rosso.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            rb.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            ParticleSystem exRossa = Instantiate(esplosioneRosso, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, -1), Quaternion.identity);
            exRossa.Play();

        }

        if(verde.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            rb.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            ParticleSystem exVerde = Instantiate(esplosioneVerde, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, -1), Quaternion.identity);
            exVerde.Play();
        }
    }
```

Restart game just set the death menu active and set some stuff to the original value, rosso and verde are the players, esplosione rosso and esplosione verde are the 2 types of particles.
Ty for help

Comment: i also tried to add waitforseconds in the restartgame method

Comment: another problem i have is that if i try to destroy the instantiated particles after the play method, it wont destroy it, i know its another question but i think it doesnt work for the same reason?

Comment: You dont show enough code that you talk about to recreate it. However you cant just throw waitforseconds in. It has to be in a coroutine which you dont mention at all.

Comment: yes, i made break() an ienumerator and used coroutine(Break()), still doesnt work

Comment: what other code do you need? @BugFinder

Comment: still doesnt work ? how dont work any error ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a coroutine Died() or Death() that wait some time before activating the death screen

```
IEnumerator Death(float seconds)
{
    return yield new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    //Call DeathScreen.SetActive(true) after calling this function
}
```

Or you can use a bool in the Update function:

```
void Update()
{
    time = 3f;
    //set boolean dead to true in the event of the player dying
    death = true;
    if(death)
        time -= 1f * Time.deltaTime;
    
    if(death && time <= 0f)
        DeathScreen.SetActive(true);
    else
        DeathScreen.SetActive(false);
...
```